# calldorado account ID

Tags: android, apk

I created an app, which uses 'Calldorado' account ID.

My code is:
https://paste.originersmc.com/4/

My account ID is: `a1-a17fe461-04f1-4a68-a8df-6a2a97f235cb`
but, sometimes, in the App appear an error like:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.calldorado.android.actionreceiver.ActionReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing account id --- Calldorado init failed! Please refer to the integration guide at my.calldorado.com.\n\tat android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2680)\n\tat android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:156)\n\tat android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1428)\n\tat android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)\n\tat android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)\n\tat android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)\n\tat com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945)\n\tat com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740)\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing account id --- Calldorado init failed! Please refer to the integration guide at my.calldorado.com.\n\tat c.Hgs.ˊ(SourceFile:1062)\n\tat com.calldorado.android.actionreceiver.ActionReceiver.onReceive(SourceFile:84)\n\tat android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2673)\n\t... 9 more\njava.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing account id --- Calldorado init failed! Please refer to the integration guide at my.calldorado.com.\n\tat c.Hgs.ˊ(SourceFile:1062)\n\tat com.calldorado.android.actionreceiver.ActionReceiver.onReceive(SourceFile:84)\n\tat android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2673)\n\tat android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:156)\n\tat android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1428)\n\tat android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)\n\tat android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)\n\tat android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)\n\tat com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945)\n\tat com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740)

Any idea to how fix that?

Comment: Hello,
Code I use is:
    apply plugin: 'calldorado'
    calldorado {
        accountId = "a1-a17fe461-04f1-4a68-a8df-6a2a97f235cb"
        appId = "b0-89dc6b78-3215-4633-940a-ba7c28eb8941"
    }

Comment: I edited the code. I can't add more, beacouse code is private (sorry).

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following command in your terminal:

`\.gradlew clean --refresh-dependencies`

This will grap the newest version of the Calldorado plugin that is causing this error. The newest version has a fix in it.

Comment: if you are not sure about your answer, you should better put it as a comment rather than as an answer. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There was an error in the plugin and a new one has been released. This is why the refresh depedencies command will "work" for you. It will basically go out on the maven repo and look for the new plugin with the fixes in and gradle will use that one instead.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Hope this answer will get some upvotes